# Two Apps handling same Uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two seperated Rails Apps handling the same uploads directory. For uploading files there is no problem because I can set custom filesystem path to do that.

There is a problem when both Apps are required to show the same uploads on different domains (`app1.com` and `app2.com`)

Where should I put/configure uploads folder to make it reachable by both apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**S3**](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

If you're using [`paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), you can [use the `s3` option](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) to upload directly to an S3 bucket, and then use the same bucket for both apps:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

This basically creates an external repository which both apps can use. The only problem would be conflicts between the two (I.E if you wanted to save the same file or something)

If you provide some more context, we'll be in a better position to recommend a decent solution

Comment: Thanks! I will make it if will not find a way to do this on my local machine - it would be great to make it more simple